# prometheus discovered service not in targets

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have my prometheus configuration which is able to discover my service however target is not added.

prometheus-sample (0 / 1 active targets)

Below is my prometheus config.

```
    - job_name: prometheus-sample
      honor_timestamps: true
      scrape_interval: 10s
      scrape_timeout: 10s
      metrics_path: /metrics
      scheme: http
      follow_redirects: true
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app]
        separator: ;
        regex: prometheus-sample
        replacement: $1
        action: keep
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
        separator: ;
        regex: "8080"
        replacement: $1
        action: keep
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
        follow_redirects: true
        namespaces:
          names:
          - prometheus-sample
```

This is my service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus-sample
  namespace: prometheus-sample
spec:
  selector:
    app: prometheus-sample
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

My pod is up and running and accepting requests. I have been able to test it using static config and it works well and am able to get the pod scraped.

What makes a discovered service not get added to targets?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue with the regex in this section. You are matching port name which is `http` but your regex is looking for `8080`.

```
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
  separator: ;
  regex: "8080"
  replacement: $1
  action: keep
```

Comment: It's for relabel. Still tried your suggestion. No impact though.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my prometheus config to:

```
    - job_name: prometheus-sample
      honor_timestamps: true
      scrape_interval: 10s
      scrape_timeout: 10s
      metrics_path: /metrics
      scheme: http
      follow_redirects: true
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
        follow_redirects: true
        namespaces:
          names:
          - prometheus-sample
```

This seems to work